# All of the dates should reflect the timezone of the current Admin User's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, timezone

While user signup  I had given the timezone field by which user save its timezone. So for this I had mentioned the  given at:

```
registration.html.erb

    <%= f.time_zone_select :time_zone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones , {prompt: 'Select TimeZone'}%>
```

and at:

```
application_controller.rb

    before_filter :set_admin_timezone

      def set_admin_timezone
        Time.zone = current_admin_user.try(:time_zone)
      end
```

So with this its saving the timezone for the user but for the whole app its not using that given timezone its using the default UTC timezone. When I am some other posts.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as what I am missing here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to show datetime in the user time zone which he has selected in the signup ?

Comment: How are you trying to access `Time` / `DateTime` / `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` objects that leads to a failure to utilize the desired time zone? For example, are `ActiveRecord` timestamp columns coming out wrong? Or are you making calls to `Time.now` (or similar)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to make it work by setting at

```
config/application.rb

config.time_zone = 'Mountain Time (US & Canada)'
```